# Android Thread / AsyncTask, ExceptionInInitializerError and RuntimeException on "runOnUiThread"

Tags: android, multithreading, exception, android-asynctask

I need your help with two Errors I´m getting on

1. Creating a Thread, where I`m creating a file
2. After the file stuff, a AsyncTask getting executed to send the file to a server (multipart/form-data)

Thats how the first part looks like:

```
public void startResultTransfer(final int timestamp, final int duration, final String correction, final float textSize, final int age, final int switch_count, final Activity activity){

    synchronized(DataTransmission.class){ 

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                FileWriter fw = null;
                //1.Check if file exists
                File file = new File(FILE_PATH);
                if(!file.exists()){
                    //File does not exists, when we have to generate the head-line
                    try {
                        fw = new FileWriter(FILE_PATH);
                        fw.append("timestamp\tduration\tcorrection\ttext_size\tage\tswitch_count"); //Headline
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                //2. Write Result
                try {
                    if(fw == null)
                        fw = new FileWriter(FILE_PATH);
                    fw.append("\n"+String.valueOf(timestamp)+"\t");
                    fw.append(""+String.valueOf(duration)+"\t");
                    fw.append(""+correction+"\t");
                    fw.append(""+String.valueOf(textSize)+"\t");
                    fw.append(""+String.valueOf(age)+"\t");
                    fw.append(""+String.valueOf(switch_count)+"\t");
                    fw.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //3. File Transfer
                if(isOnline(activity))
                    transferFileToServer(activity);
            }
        }.start();

    }
}
```

The function "transferFileToServer" looks like this:

```
public synchronized void transferFileToServer(Activity activity){
    String id = id(activity);
    File file = new File(FILE_PATH);

    if(id != null && file.exists()){
        final String url = URL+id;
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TransmissionTask task = new TransmissionTask();
                task.execute(url);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Now, I`m getting an "ExceptionInInitializerError" with the explanatory message

> Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"

at the line "activity.runOnUiThread".

In the first function I need to call "transferFileToServer" after some pre settings. But the function should be called unattached from the first function, too.

Should I maybe implement a MessageHandler for executing the AsyncTask at the end of Thread?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html

Or should I maybe Change the "AsyncTask" in the "transferFileToServer" function to a Thread, because I don`t do any UI operations?

Edit: The method started from the Async-Task

```
class TransmissionTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    public TransmissionTask() {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        synchronized(DataTransmission.class){
            try {

                HttpURLConnection urlConn;
                java.net.URL mUrl = new java.net.URL(params[0]);
                urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();
                urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                String boundary = "---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
                String contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary;
                urlConn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);

                DataOutputStream request = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream());
                request.writeBytes("\r\n--"+boundary+"\r\n");
                request.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\""+FILE_NAME+"\"\r\n");
                request.writeBytes("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n");

                File myFile = new File(FILE_PATH);
                int size = (int) myFile.length();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
                try {
                    BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
                    buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                    buf.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                request.write(bytes);
                request.writeBytes("\r\n--"+boundary+"--\r\n");

                request.flush();
                request.close();

                InputStream responseStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConn.getInputStream());

                BufferedReader responseStreamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream));
                String line = "";
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = responseStreamReader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                responseStreamReader.close();

                String response = stringBuilder.toString();
                responseStream.close();
                urlConn.disconnect();

                return response;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(result != null){
            if(result.toLowerCase().contains("erfolgreich")){
            //If successfull delete File
            File file = new File(FILE_PATH);
            file.delete();
            }
        }   

    }

}
```

Comment: While not directly the problem behind your *current* error, by all appearances you are trying to use runOnUiThread to put what is likely a network operation onto the UI thread - the **exact opposite** of what you should be doing, which is running that in the background.

Comment: Hi Chris, thx. Thats what i thought, too. Ok I will do it without a async-task

Comment: The problem that we don't see your async-task class. can you post it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `runOnUiThread`:

```
public synchronized void transferFileToServer(Activity activity){
String id = id(activity);
File file = new File(FILE_PATH);

if(id != null && file.exists()){
    final String url = URL+id;

      TransmissionTask task = new TransmissionTask();
      task.execute(url); 
  }
}
```

The main idea of `AsyncTask` to run background operation/logic without Threads or Handlers.

You don't need wrap `AsyncTask` with additional Thread and bind with UI Thread what you did

From your code:

```
 public void startResultTransfer(/* ... */){

 ....

new Thread() {

    .....
     transferFileToServer(/* ... */); // its wrong!!! 
    ....


 }.start()

}
```

`transferFileToServer` starts your `AsyncTask` and you run it not in main UI Thread but in single Thread.

This is a problem.

Start your `AsyncTask` from Activity.

Comment: Thx, Maxim. This is how it looked first. But i got a "ExceptionInInitializerError". Now, i added a additional function, where i`m doing the data transfer. This function can now be started from the Thread in "startResultTransfer" and I changed the Async-Task in "transferFileToServer" to a Thread, where I`m starting the data transfer, too.

Comment: your design seems too complicated, what do you want to do in one sentence?

Comment: 1. I want to add information to a txt file "startResultTransfer()" -> After that, i need to send the txt-file as "multipart/form-data" to a server, after a succesfull transfer i`m deleting the file -> If there is no internet-connection, I´m storing the information, as long as there is no internet connection in the txt-file. 2. If the internet connection exists again, i`m checking if the txt-file exisits. If the txt-file exists, i`m trying to resend it to the server.

Comment: If you run your my example where do you get `ExceptionInInitializerError`?

Comment: on "TransmissionTask task = new TransmissioNTask(); task.execute(url)"